# Bootstrap 3 responsive table breaks layout but works

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3's `.table-responsive` class and am wondering why it does not cater to `md` screen types. here are some screenshots:

[image: This is when the screen is resized to <code>col-md-*</code>]

[image]

Comment: provide the fiddle or a link. And while you are at it, check the @media for the size it breaks at and check the width percentage

Comment: I've found the fix. not as preferred, but it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988677/issue-on-responsive-tables-in-bootstrap